# Time Now() Not working with Custom TimeZone

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have my server in America/Chicago, I am posting current time with data in one of my filed qu_time. I am from India,so I need Asia/Kolkata as timezone for insert current time in my database. I have tried many from stackflow but I am not success, Can anyone please suggest me what should I do for it ?
My current query is like below

```html
$upd_qry = "update tbl_quotes 
                set qu_status='".$_GET['status']."', qu_time=NOW()              
                where _quid='".$_GET['quotes_id']."'";
  $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$upd_qry);
```

Thanks

Comment: So you are saying that by using `NOW()` you are getting `America/Chicago` timzone time?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Yes...You are right, because my server is located there.

Comment: Check the answer provided by me

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to set the timezone and get its value. First, is to set it on php end using:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

and instead of using `now()`, use:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

to get current datetime in mysql datetime format.

Second, is to set on mysql server and use `now()` to get current datetime. To set the timezone on server, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql), on this link there is an answer with 260 upvotes, follow it and every thing will be fine.

**Note:** Keep in mind that by setting the php timezone you cannot get the right datetime using `now()` function, as `now()` is a mysql function, it return the datetime according to mysql server's settings.